# Table rendering issue from API responce in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, rendering

I am new to react and facing some issues with a table display.
When I am trying to render data using State entire string value gets rendered, instead of an actual table.

A small snippet of data displayed in the browser:

[image]

But when I copy-paste the data from the screen to the `render()` method, the table gets displayed properly.
The current render method-

```js
render() {
  this.setValueForState();
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {this.state.Header}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.Detail}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get the following error in the console. I have made sure that there are no BLANK spaces in the data.

> index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of `<tr>`.
>   Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of `<tbody>`.

I looked up this error online for the above error and removed all Blank spaces from the result string.

Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.Header` and `this.state.Detail` are strings, which are getting rendered as text nodes.
As the error message states, you can not put text nodes inside `<tr>` or `<tbody>` tags as you have done.
HTML tables need the text nodes to be inside `<td>` tags.
See below for valid table markup.

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>{this.state.Header}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{this.state.Detail}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove some **whitespace**. you can try with below

```
<tr key={id}>{this.state.Header}</tr>;
```